# Corsair Force SSD in Windows XP HDD-Erase quarterly necessary?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, ssd

I upgraded to a a Corsair Force SSD. Sadly I have to use Windows XP on the work-partition (will be replaced with Windows 7 within 1 year *sigh*).

Now I read that I should create an image of the whole partition and wipe the partition with HDD-Erase afterwards every quarter year or so in order to keep the SSD's performance.

How do you think abou t that?

Comment: I don't know anything about SSD drives, so don't read anything into this when I ask: Where did you read that? If that is true, I would not care about the speed increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP does not support TRIM by nature. You would need software to erase the data as it is being deleted. Would it be possible to upgrade to Windows 7 and use WinXP in a virtual environment?

Performance could start to suffer within a week if the SSD is trying to write to parts of the SSD that has already had data deleted.

Comment: Using a virtual WinXP-environment sounds like a very good idea. I think I can even order this in my company.

Comment: You can use VirtualBox which is a free and very decent visualization program. You would use your WinXP license in this virtual environment and then use the Win7 as the primary host.

Comment: When making the virtual environment, you'll be given two options for creating your hard drive. Dynamically growing or fixed. Usually for performance reasons, I will use the fixed size hard drive as it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks I'm familiar with the concepts of VMs and am using them in private already. However as I've told you I'm working for a company. Therefore they have to create a virtual work environment which is also connected to the companies ethernet. They are building a SAN currently for that purpose. I'll be able to get a virtual work environment by september which is good enough for me. Thanks for the advice.